# problem with generating PDF and session_start()

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I've been using PDF class produced by [R&OS](http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/)  successfully in a number of recent developments. I'd like to use it in a page that performs a database query before generating a PDF (it's basically a summary of the session, so I'm using session_id() as part of the query)

All is fine if I run this in Firefox - not fine in IE. I *think* the loading of session_start() is doing something with headers that's upsetting IE as it appears unable to load the page (comment off session_start and the page loads fine).

I'm getting a little concerned as, on further investigation, it appears that R&OS is not supported ... **bad newbie learning experience** and I really don't want to have to try adopt another class system this late in the day.

Have you any thoughts as to what I could try next?
Thankx
G

Answer (score 1):

`session_start()` does indeed send some headers when it is used.  However, you can control this particular functionality using the [session_cache_limiter()](http://php.net/session_cache_limiter) function.

From browsing through the manual comments, it sounds like IE has some particular idiosyncrasies when dealing with binary content.  One of the suggested solutions is to set a `must-validate` header before calling `session_start()` when you are trying to force a file download on the same page:

```
session_cache_limiter("must-revalidate"); 
session_start();
```

Maybe that will work for you.  There are other headers that might work as well... give the comments section on that manual page a read, it looks like there's a variety of tricks you might be able to use.

Comment: Thank you so much that did the trick. Really appreciate your reply
G